# Having trouble when installing rgee at "2.Creating a Python enviroment(rgee)"

Tags: python, r, google-earth-engine, rgee

codes are simple:

```
library(rgee) 
ee_install()`
```

what shows in console are as follow:

```
ee_install()
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Python configuration used to create rgee --
python:         E:/miniconda/python.exe
libpython:      E:/miniconda/python39.dll
pythonhome:     E:/miniconda
version:        3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
ee:             [NOT FOUND]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1. Removing the previous Python Environment (rgee), if it exists ...
2. Creating a Python Environment (rgee)
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -
An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : An error occur when ee_install was creating the Python Environment. Run ee_clean_pyenv() and restart the R session, before trying again.
```

I've been trying run "ee_clean_pyenv()" and restart but it didn't work. anyone knows some solutions?

Comment: Can you reach the https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json URL from your browser? Is your R machine connected to the internet? Like the error message says, it may be a temporary problem. How long has this been happening?

Comment: I can open the link but still cant complete 2. . my pc is connected to internet.